# Replace (,) with (',')

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I want to replace a single comma (,) with (',').

For example:

```
"text,text,text" with "text','text','text".
```

I tried

```
MyText.Replace(',',"','");
```

but can't get anything working properly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Remember that Replace (as any string method) returns a new string with the result of the operation. You need to reassign the result of replace to your string

Comment: Should the output have quotes on the ends, or be formatted as `text','text','text` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
MyText = MyText.Replace(",","','");
```

There are two .Replace methods on strings. One for single characters and one for strings.
When you `','` that defines a single character so it goes to the single character version of the method. If you use double quotes then it defines a string so that version of the method is selected.

Docs on the string replace method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks Daniel. This works
I was trying to replace a char with string hence, resulting an invalid expression.